# Equivalence of norms in $C^1[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider the set of all mappings of class $C^1$ defined from $[-1,1]$ into $\mathbb{R}$.

Consider the two norms  $N_1=\sup_{x\in[-1,1]}|f(x)|$ and $N_2=|f(0)|+\sup_{x\in[-1,1]}|f'(x)|$.

Are they equivalent?

Comment: Will you please share your attempts also?

Comment: sorry, set of functions of class C1

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/595047/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.  Consider the sequence of functions given by
$$
f_n(x) = \sqrt{x^2 + \frac 1n}
$$
whose derivatives are given by
$$
f_n'(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + \frac 1n}}
$$

Comment: Note that the sequence is Cauchy with respect to one norm but not the other

Comment: uhmm okay but what about Norm N1 and the Norm N=$\int_{-1}^1|f(x)|dx$ are they equivelant ? i managed to prove that N<2N1 but im stuck proving N1<mN for m being a positive constant

Comment: If you'd like a full answer to this question, you should post it separately.

Comment: That being said, I'm fairly certain that these are also *not* equivalent.

Comment: taking $f(x)=x^n$ would do the job??

Comment: Yes, I think that would do the job for the same reason

Comment: @MohamadMisto well a clue that might help in such situations is that in one case the norms have a derivative and in others it is lacking. It's not a mathematical argument but it helps to see that they're kinda measuring different things.

Comment: Alternatively, consider
$$
f_n(x) = \frac{1}{(1 + (nx)^2)}
$$

Answer (score 1):

No they are not. The second is stronger than the first.

Take $f_n(x)=\sin (nx)$. Then $\sup \lvert\, f_n(x)\rvert=1$, while $\lvert\,f(0)\rvert+\sup\lvert\,f'(x)\rvert=n$.

On the other hand,

$$
f(x)=f(0)+\int_{0}^x f'(t)\,dt
$$
and hence
$$
\sup\lvert\, f(x)\rvert\le \lvert\,f(0)\rvert+\sup\lvert\, f'(x)\rvert.
$$

Answer (score 0):

A nice example is a sequence of bumps which lose height much slower than they lose width. For instance a smoothed out form of a function which is zero except for an isosceles triangle of height $1/n $ and width $1/n^2$. This goes to zero uniformly but the derivative blows up. So it converges in one norm but is not even bounded in the other.