# d1 and d2 metrics on C[0,1] - topologically inequivalent. Why?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I know that all $d_p$ metrics are topologically equivalent on $\mathbb{R}$. I also know it is not the case for C[0,1] (space of continuous functions). To show that I can use a sequence of functions $f_n = x^n$, which converges in (a topology induced by) $d_1$, but it doesn't in $d_\infty$.

Now I would like to show that $d_1$ and $d_2$ are not topologically equivalent. I have tried and failed to find similar counterexample. I also tried to find a set which is open in one but not the other.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Btw, I am aware of similar question here: [Deciding whether two metrics are topologically equivalent in the space $C^1([0,1])$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/595047). It does not however fully answer my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to show that the norms $L_1$ and $L_2$ are not equivalent on $C[0,1]$. Let's first note that $||f||_1\le ||f||_2$ (Jensen's ineq). Now the fact that the norms are not equivalent already follows from the fact that there exist sequences Cauchy under the first norm but not under the second.  But let us get a concrete example. Take $f_n = n$ on $[0,1/n^2]$ and decreasing linearly t0 $0$ on $]1/n^2, 2/n^2]$, and then $0$ from $2/n^2$ to $1$. Clearly $||f_n||_1 \to 0$ but $||f_n||_2 \ge 1$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1):

The existence of such a sequence as the $f_n$ is enough for $d_1$ and $d_\infty$.

But it's harder for $d_1$ and $d_2$. These metrics are both incomplete, with completions $L^1([0,1])$ and $L^2([0,1])$  resp. and the completions *are* homeomorphic (so the metrics on the completion *are* equivalent topologically), as all separable Banach spaces are. So $(C([0,1]), d_1)$ and $(C([0,1]), d_2)$ could be topologically equivalent, though I have a feeling they might not be. They're pretty similar though as dense subalgebras of homeomorphic Banach algebras.

*Added* In Bessaga and Pelczynksi's great book on infinite-dimensional topology I found an exercise with an explicit homeomorphism found by Mazur between $L^p([0,1]$ and $L^q([0,1])$: $H_{pq}(f)(t) = |f(t)|^{p \over q} \cdot \operatorname{sgn}(f(t))$, where $\operatorname{sgn}(x) = -1$ for $x < 0$, $1$ for $x > 0$ and $0 $ for $x=0$. It seems to me that this $H_{12}$ restricts to a homeomorphism between $C([0,1], d_1)$ and $C([0,1], d_2)$ as well?

This shows the spaces are topologically the same. But equivalence of metric requires the **identity** to be a homeomorphism. I doubt that this is the case here.

Comment: Thanks Henno, I will look into L^p further. Just for your info, the fact that those metrics are not topologically equivalent is stated but not proved in my lecture notes, hence I am looking for a proof.

Comment: @ElChorro The fussy thing about this is that it's easy to show that the two have different Cauchy sequences (consider for instance $f_n(x)=\begin{cases} n^{1/2} & x \in [0,1/n] \\ x^{-1/2} & x \in [1/n,1] \end{cases}$ which is Cauchy in $d_1$ and not in $d_2$) but Cauchy sequences are not a topological invariant (consider $x_n=1/n$ on $(0,1)$ and its image through the homeomorphism $\tan(\pi x - \pi/2)$).

Comment: @Ian that was my issue as well. It's a well-known fact that any two Fréchet (metric TVS with an invariant metric and complete in that metric) spaces with the same density are homeomorphic. The fact that it might at all be possible is the non-completeness.

Comment: We need a convergent sequence in one metric but not in the other. This is necessary and sufficient as all metric topologies are determined by sequences

Comment: @Elchorro I added a possible homeomorphism

Comment: Hmm, I find it difficult to verify if it is indeed a homeomorphism. If it was, it would contradict lecture notes provided by my lecturer which claim that the topological spaces induced by those metrics are not the same. I am going to bring it to my lecturer on Monday I am not convinced either way.

Comment: @ElChorro Metrics on a set $X$ are called topologically equivalent when the identity is a homeomorphism between the induced spaces. This means that convergence  under one metric is equivalent to convergence under the other metric (with the same limit). This seems to be stronger than that the resulting topological spaces are homeomorphic (using a homeomorphism $h$ of your own choosing), then $x_n \rightarrow x$ iff $h(x_n) \rightarrow h(x)$.

Comment: I see the difference now. Thank you very much for this clarification.

Comment: @orangeskid has a nice and actually quite simple example of a sequence that shows that the metrics are not equivalent, even though I still believe the resulting metric spaces *are* homeomorphic.

Comment: I've seen that example you cited due to Mazur also used to justify why Holder's inequality involves Holder conjugates: $f |f|^{p/q} \operatorname{sgn}(f)=|f|^{p/q+1}$, and $p/q+1=p$ iff $q=p'$. Then we know that Holder's inequality is the only possible inequality of its type as soon as we know that there are functions in $L^p$ which are in no other $L^r$. (I took this from Royden and Fitzpatrick.)